# Get value in jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

Here is my code

jquery code

```
$("input#shopName").autocomplete({
    source: "getShop.php",
    minLength: 2
});
```

The JSON value return from PHP as below

```
if(isset($_GET["term"])){

$query=$_GET["term"];
    $result = $dataset->get_custom_record("SELECT * FROM mc_shop WHERE shop_title like  '%" . $query . "%'  ORDER BY id");
}

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $row_array['id'] = $row['id'];
        $row_array['value'] =$row['shop_title'];

        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

autocomplete is working fine but while selecting the value from autocomplete I need put  the corresponding "id" value inside one hidden variable I don't know how to do>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$("input#shopName").autocomplete({
    source: "getShop.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) { 
        $("#theHidden").val(ui.item.id) 
    }
});
```

See http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select

Comment: I am getting all value in select query but in while loop I am using only id and value suppose I need to use other value for other displays. How to handle this? example I have id, name, and description on select I need to display description too in another div.

Comment: @Elankeeran - `$("#otherDiv").html(ui.item.description);`

Comment: I don't know if it's been changed recently, but I have had to `return false;` to get the event to stop propagating and prevent textbox value from being overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to get chosen value onClick

```
   $( "#searchText" ).bind( "autocompleteselect", function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui['item']['value']);
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more context around your answer? Like why this works, or some information about what it's doing?

Answer (score -2):

This works for me fantastically:

```
$(ui)[0].item.label
$(ui)[0].item.value
```