# Ajax jquery autocomplete for hidden id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a mysql table `client`:

`client_id   client_address  client_name`.

I am using js autocomplete, that brings back the value `client_address` based in the selected input.

The label used is `address` and `name`, and the value brought back is `client_address`. I am already using the select callback to use the `ui` in another ajax script that shows an html table.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
 $( "#clientsearch" ).autocomplete({
  source: 'backend_search_addressWT.php',
  minLength: 2, 
  select: function(event, ui) {
    showUser(ui.item.value)
    }
 });
});
</script>
```

backend_search_addressWT.php:

```
<?php
    require_once 'config.php';

    //get search term
    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];

    //get matched data from skills table
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_address LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'");
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = array (
            'label' => $row['client_address'].' - '.$row['client_name'],
            'value' => $row['client_address'],
            );
    }

    //return json data
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

What I would like to do is get the `client_id` for the selected client, to be submitted as a hidden variable in the form.

How do I get the `client_id` to be brought back as a separate value? I have tried adding on a value2 to the array, and then using the select function on this:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
        showUser(ui.item.value),
        $('#hiddenID').ui.item.value2
        }
```

But this seems to throw off the autocomplete. Should I add it to the label and then try split it?

I have looked at [Get value in jquery autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766726/get-value-in-jquery-autocomplete) but I am already using the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use comma (,) use ; becouse you are writing code inside function. try as below.

```
select: function(event, ui) {

        showUser(ui.item.value);
        $("#hiddenID").val(ui.item.value);

        }
```